# How to use the aggregate command with the MongoDB connector in Matlab?

Tags: c++, mongodb, matlab, nosql, aggregate

I have just started using MongoDB with Matlab (R2021b). Currently, I am using the `mongoc` class (https://ch.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mongoc.html) to connect to my MongoDB database.

However, after going through the documentation I am unable to find the `aggregate` method equivalent to the command in MongoDB. Is is possible to run aggregation operations with the other available methods (`find`, `insert`,  `update`, `remove`) or is there a raw `db.runCommand()` method as described in the documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/)? Am I constrained with the `find` method for querying?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!